# Timeout expired on a C# method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an already running stored procedure on mssql that was running ok. 3 days ago, running the same procedure in code started giving me Timeout expired. Have tried checking if there are any running process on the underlying table but there appears to be none. Checked for deadlock situations and there's none as well. Can anyone suggest what to do next to get this resolved?

Here's the code

```
public DataSet rptPaymentsByDateOptions(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, string level, string sessionID, string degreeID, string programID, string jrnalSrce)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        DbCommand cmdSem = db.GetStoredProcCommand("[iSchool].[rptCurrentSem]");
        DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("[iFinance].[rptPaymentsByDateOptions]");
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "DateFrom", DbType.Date, dateFrom);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "DateTo", DbType.Date, dateTo);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Level", DbType.String, level);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "SessionID", DbType.String, sessionID);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "DegreeID", DbType.String, degreeID);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "ProgramID", DbType.String, programID);
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "JrnalSrce", DbType.String, jrnalSrce);
        db.LoadDataSet(cmdSem, ds, "rptCurrentSem");
        db.LoadDataSet(cmd, ds, "rptPaymentsByDateOptions"); //Timeout error here
        return ds;
    }
```

If i execute the rptPaymentsDateOptions stored procedure in management studio, it runs successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the timeout

[DbCommand.CommandTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could also review your tables and data to see if any additional indexes might speed up the query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ChrisBint, I realized that detaching and re-attaching the database resolved the timeout issue. It makes me think there was something blocking it. I however, will set the DbCommand.CommandTimeout Property if this should re-occur. Thank you